# How to change day of date format PHP/laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
public function store(ContractRequest $request,$operatorId)
{
 //dd($request->all());

    $contractData = $request->all();
    $contractData['operator_id'] = $operatorId;

    if ($this->contract->create($contractData)) {
        return redirect()->route('admin.operator.{id}.contracts.index',[$operatorId])->with('success', 'Contract
        successfully
        created.');

    }

        return redirect()->route('admin.contracts.index')->with('error', 'Contract could not be created.');
    }
```

my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title', 'Start Date:', ['class'=>'col-sm-2 control-label'])!!}
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        {!! Form::date('start_date',null, ["class"=>"form-control",'required'])!!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title', 'End Date:', ['class'=>'col-sm-2 control-label'])!!}
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        {!! Form::date('end_date',null, ["class"=>"form-control"])!!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title', 'Remarks:', ['class'=>'col-sm-2 control-label'])!!}
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        {!! Form::textarea('remark',null, ["class"=>"form-control",'cols'=>'10','rows'=>'5'])!!}
    </div>
</div>
```

my question :This is contract form and generally `contract` start form `01` day end at `30,29 or 31` day of month.
if user select `2016-2-4` as `start date` and `2017-05-31` `as end date` then start date should be saved as 2016-2-`1`.How can make this ,start date day should always be one ie`1`

start data `2016-o2-o4 should be saved as`2016-02-01 ie `1` at end for day

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, could you perhaps rephrase the question a bit? As for dealing with dates, have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @Qirel i have made some changes.i need your help

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to go about this is first instantiating this as a Carbon object (I'm saying Carbon because it makes this a lot easier, and already ships with Laravel). Once done, you can simply set the `day` on that object, and that's it. Note that Laravel automatically handles Carbon/DateTime objects, so you can actually save that straight to the database and Laravel will handle turning it into a correctly formatted string. It would look something like this:

```
$date = (new Carbon($request->start_date))->day(1);
```

That will set the day to the first of the month, and leave the rest as is.